# C++ map segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use an `map` with `string` key, but it's not working and I couldn't figure out why.
I would like to have some help to understand C++ fundamentals about the usage of this so essential structure.

**model.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "../prs/ast.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace ast;

typedef map<string, Variable> Map;
typedef pair<string, Variable> Element;

namespace model{

    class Warehouse {
    public:
        Map stock;

        Warehouse(){
            Map* _stock = new Map();
            stock = *_stock;
        }

        Variable* get(string id){
            Map::iterator it = stock.find(id);
            if (it != stock.end()){
                return &(*it).second;
            }
            else {
                return __define__(id);
            }
        }

        Variable* __define__(string id){
            Variable* defined = new Variable(id);
            stock.insert(Element(id, *defined));
            return defined;
        }
    };

    static Warehouse* WAREHOUSE;
};
```

**model.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "model.hpp"

using namespace std;

namespace model {
    Warehouse* WAREHOUSE = new Warehouse();
}
```

> In this context, `Variable` is a project object defined in `ast`
>   namespace already tested, as well `WAREHOUSE` pointer is working accordingly, with class
>   initialized

The instruction `stock.find(id)` is throwing the mentioned error message: *`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`*, what I suppose means `stock` isn't correct initialized.

What is exactly happening with `stock` initialization done at `Warehouse` constructor?
I understand that `new` keyword `alloc`s the `map` and dereference its returned point would store the structure at `stock` `Warehouse` member attribute.

Am I misunderstand it?

Comment: `Map* _stock = new Map();` dynamically allocates a `Map` and `stock = *_stock;` dereferences the pointer to assign a **copy** of the `Map` to the member variable. When the constructor ends the pointer goes out of scope and the originally allocated memory is leaked. I don't know why you're using `new` and raw pointers in this code. Your segfault is likely related to manual memory management (memory leak, double-delete, use-after-free, etc).

Comment: There is a whole bunch of nonos in this code. 1. `using namespace` should never be used in a header file, and `using namespace std` just never, period. 2. Double underscores are verboten. 3. `new` is the past millennium keyword, use smart pointers. But an `std::map` should almost never be allocated on the free store anyway. 4. Everything is public, why? 5. Memory leaks in the form of `x = *new X`. Do you have Java background by any chance? When programming C++, it's best to forget most of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WAREHOUSE` is a `static` variable defined in a header. What this means is that every source file that includes that header gets its own copy of this variable, initialized to `nullptr`. Only one source file sets its own copy to a non-null value. Presumably, some other source file in the code not shown attempts to dereference its copy.

Make it

```
extern Warehouse* WAREHOUSE;
```